# How to change SSLv3 to TLS?

Tags: ssl, openssl

In my `Rails application` when user pay for products get error.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)
```

Due to `payment gateway does not support SSLv3` more. So need to set the TLS

```
protocol in the OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.
ssl_version = :TLSv1
```

But i tried lots but not getting how to `set it ssl_version.`

#### UPDATE

Now, I found path in apache server

```
Edited: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf

>  SSLProtocol all
Change to 
>  SSLProtocol  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

After restart apache server.

But still get same error...any one here can help...

SSLSCAN Result:

```
Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  AECDH-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  256 bits  PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  168 bits  PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  AECDH-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  SEED-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  AECDH-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    SSLv3  128 bits  PSK-RC4-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  56 bits   DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-RC4-MD5
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    AECDH-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Failed    SSLv3  0 bits    NULL-SHA256
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    NULL-SHA
Rejected  SSLv3  0 bits    NULL-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  AECDH-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  256 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  256 bits  PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  168 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  168 bits  PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  AECDH-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-SEED-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  SEED-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  AECDH-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
Failed    TLSv1  128 bits  PSK-RC4-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  56 bits   DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  40 bits   EXP-RC4-MD5
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    AECDH-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA
Failed    TLSv1  0 bits    NULL-SHA256
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    NULL-SHA
Rejected  TLSv1  0 bits    NULL-MD5
```

Thanks

Comment: The certificate error is probably due to the certificate become out of date, or it cannot access it, or the appropriate software to use it is not available.

Comment: my site works perfect for certificates but when tried to payment at that time got this error..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this information is useful to you but the Nginx developers stated in their announcement for [h2](https://www.nginx.com/blog/how-nginx-plans-to-support-http2/) that Nginx runs as a proxy with a [modern config](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) and you don't have to wait for applications to implement the protocol, they will just talk to Nginx like before while the users benefit from the new protocol (or TLS in your case). I'm not saying go and install Nginx, just look at what you actual problem is.

Comment: Please run `sslscan <HOST>`, where `<HOST>` is the hostname of the problematic SSL server, and post the result here.

Comment: sslscan result added in questions. Can you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got solutions my self.

I solved all protocol error still error display due to old version of activemerchant gem.

So, after changes of Sagepay gateway, its not in gem so once i updated gem of activemerchant then auto get updates of SagePay Gateway which resolved my error.

Thanks